# C++ casting non-pointer instances of a custom class

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, polymorphism, subclass

Lets say I have class A and it has a subclass B.

```
class A 
{
public:
    A(){};
}

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int value){ foo = value };
    int foo;
}
```

B is a subclass of A with an int foo.

Okay now lets say I do the following:

```
std::vector<A> mylist;
B myB(5); //Create a new instance of class B
mylist.push_back(myB); //Add b to my vector of A.
```

Now I want to access an element of mylist and type cast it to type B and retrieve 'foo'. Is the following legal?

```
B *instance = (B *)&mylist[0];
```

I've tried doing this in my project but if I were to print out the value of foo it would be incorrect:

```
std::cout<<instance->foo<<std::endl; // This does not give me 5. It gives me a garbage number.
```

The problems stems from the fact that I don't know the proper way to cast non-pointers in C++.

Comment: `Okay now lets say I do the following:`  Don't.  Since you shouldn't do that, the rest of your question becomes a moot point.

Comment: ^Well then I'm trying to figure out the right way to cast a non-pointer...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the slicing problem in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)

Comment: If your vector holds A objects, then it only is supposed to know about A objects.  Let's say you now change the vector to hold pointers to A objects.  Still, the vector should only know about A pointers and you should work solely with the A interface.  So what I'm saying is that you should rethink your design.  Maybe introduce virtual functions.

Comment: There is no right way.

Answer (score 4):

When you write `mylist.push_back(myB)`, a *slice* occurs. The `mylist` stores `A` objects. So what happens is that your `B` is converted to an `A`, losing all of the things that are in `B` and not `A`. Just the `A` is stored. You cannot retrieve the lost pieces.

It is the same as doing:

```
B myB(5);
A a(myB);
```

In order to have polymorphic behaviour, you need to make `A` be a polymorphic class, and also refer to the objects by pointers, i.e. `A *` .

So you need to add at least one virtual function to `A` (virtual destructor would be a good idea), and have your vector store pointers. For example:

```
std::vector< A* > mylist;
mylist.push_back( new myB(5) );
B *instance = dynamic_cast<B *>(mylist[0]);
```

Now, this code is OK but you have to be very careful about deleting memory you new'd. To solve that for you there is `shared_ptr` which is a ref-counted pointer. I made the following test case which seems to work (disclaimer - I'm not an expert in polymorphism with smart pointers, so I hope there is not a stealthy error here)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A 
{
public:
    A(){};
    virtual ~A() {}
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int value): foo(value) {}
    int foo;
    ~B() { std::cout << "Destructor B(" << foo << ")" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<A> > mylist;

// Test the polymorphic behaviour
//  mylist.push_back( std::make_shared<A>() );

// create directly into container
    mylist.push_back( std::make_shared<B>(5) );

// via pointer
    B *temp_b = new B(6);
    mylist.push_back( std::shared_ptr<B>(temp_b) );

    std::shared_ptr<B> instance  = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>( mylist[0] );
    if ( !instance )
       std::cout << "Item was not a B" << std::endl;
    else
       std::cout << instance->foo << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical example of slicing issues in C++.

You should store pointer in the vector to easily avoid them. If you do not wanna to deal with raw pointers, use smart pointers.

Comment: What is slicing? It there a way for me to do it like this without pointers?

Comment: @lizusek: how would a type field help though? The slicing would still occur when pushing.